# How to close an editor programatically in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

We want to close all opened files of a project (IProject) in eclipse when we delete it. I can reach IFiles via members method of a project. I want to close deleted project's all files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get references to the open editors on a page with:

```java
IWorkbenchWindow workbenchWindow = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
IWorkbenchPage page = workbenchWindow.getActivePage();

IEditorReference[] editorRefs = page.getEditorReferences();
```

Get the actual editor part from the references with:

```java
IEditorPart editor = editorRefs[index].getEditor(true);
```

Get the editor input:

```java
IEditorInput input = editor.getEditorInput();
```

Get the file the editor is editing:

```java
IFile file = (IFile)input.getAdapter(IFile.class);
```

Close an editor:

```java
page.closeEditor(editor, true);
```

Comment: You can also directly get the `IEditorInput` from the editorReference (i.e. `editorRefs[index].getEditorInput()`). This prevents the editor from being created.

Comment: Thanks greg it worked. Herrman thank you for the help too.