# Can I prevent an RCP editor from loading

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I'm loading a data-file into an RCP 3.x application. The flow typically results in the data being shown in an RCP editor.

But, if the input file is corrupt, the data cannot be loaded.  In this circumstance I do not with the editor to open, by trying to cancel the `PlotEditor.init()` flow by throwing a `PartInitException`.

But, this still leaves an empty editor.

Any tips?

Comment: The editor could close itself or display the error message with a button to do so (instead of the text area): https://stackoverflow.com/q/37374791/6505250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once Eclipse is told to open the editor it will always display an editor - either the requested editor or the 'error occurred' editor. I don't know of any way to change this.

So if the data may be corrupt you need to validate it before attempting to open an editor.

Comment: Hey, @greg-449, howlger has provided a link to where you demonstrated how to close the editor: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37374992/92441

Comment: @ianmayo But it will still open first, at best you would get flickering.

Answer (score 0):

I was working through the call stack, and I saw the following code. It looks like the actual UI elements start being processed at line 353.  So, I thought that if I could get the method to return at line 336 or 341, then the editor UI may not get created.

[image: Part initialisation source]

Comment: Returning at 336 / 341 is what actually happens - `handlePartInitException`  causes the Error Editor to display instead.